# Converting character string to multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I want to get the following table

```
library(tidyverse)
tb3 <-
  tibble(
    NO1    = c(1, 2)
  , Item   = c("Wheat Flour Bag", "Rice Basmati Broken (Average Quality)")
  , Quan   = c("20 Kg", "1 Kg")
  , Price1 = c(805.00, 90.00)
  , Price2 = c(836.76, 101.52)
  , No2    = c(1, 2)
  )

# A tibble: 2 x 6
    NO1 Item                                  Quan  Price1 Price2   No2
  <dbl> <chr>                                 <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 Wheat Flour Bag                       20 Kg    805   837.     1
2     2 Rice Basmati Broken (Average Quality) 1 Kg      90   102.     2
```

from the following scrap

```
tb1 <- "  1 Wheat Flour Bag                      20 Kg        805.00      836.76    1"
tb1
[1] "  1 Wheat Flour Bag                      20 Kg        805.00      836.76    1"

tb2 <- "  2 Rice Basmati Broken (Average Quality)1 Kg          90.00      101.52    2"
tb2
[1] "  2 Rice Basmati Broken (Average Quality)1 Kg          90.00      101.52    110.00   85.00    92.86     100.00   75.00    76.63      80.00    70.00      70.00     70.00   70.00     74.71     80.00   90.00      90.00     90.00   70.00    73.19      80.00   2"
```

Comment: Since some of the lines don't have a delimiter between the columns, you are going to have to go for a regex solution. An appropriate one will likely need more info than just the first two lines

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how are you trying to delimit columns?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions could be considered, e.g.

- Use of `substr`, given your input seems to have fixed-width columns.
- Use of REGEX (`grep`, `grepl`, etc.) to pattern-match the different parts.
- ...